# Amazon S3: How to display custom message instead of access denied 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to access the uploaded files on the Amazon s3 bucket using the Rails application. When I click on the specific link, getting following error.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.  <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<X-Amz-Expires>600</X-Amz-Expires>
<Expires>2016-07-20T22:22:58Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2016-07-20T22:33:21Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>461898B9DD2599A6</RequestId>
<HostId>
jAarpDNUJn+SygprDBXP/EnI9vN5sAR2OUqXSQ7UwsIXSAB6HR9OoYpmd3RXmxXv9AlZG+wsL8s=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

How to display custom error message instead of "Access Denied" page?

Comment: I think this post can help you
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859624/create-my-own-error-page-for-amazon-s3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859624/create-my-own-error-page-for-amazon-s3)

Comment: @MaverickTan it works for s3 bucket serving static web site, otherwise its not possible to have custom messages

Comment: @FrédéricHenri is correct, and the static web site feature is not compatible with signed URLs.  I came up with a way to customize S3 REST endpoint errors by deploying HAProxy in EC2 as a front-end for the bucket, using Lua to inject an XSL stylesheet [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33109592/1695906).  If such a solution gives anyone nightmares, I'm not responsible, but there is no built-in way to do something similar.  CloudFront, in front of a bucket, allows *static* custom error files, but to use that optimally, your URLs need to be signed for CloudFront instead of S3.

Comment: I am trying to configure it using http://blog.celingest.com/en/2013/12/12/cloudfront-configuring-custom-error-pages/ steps but not working.

Comment: I am trying to configure it in Rails application with [carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and I have also tried to configure using   http://blog.celingest.com/en/2013/12/12/cloudfront-configuring-custom-error-pages/ steps but not working.